# How to order a python list, based on another list

Tags: python

Let's suppose we have the following list containing some document names:

```
documents = ['document1.txt', 'document2.txt', 'document3.txt', 'document4.txt', 'document5.txt']
```

And we also have another python list containing some metric related to the documents above:

```
metrics = [0.2, 0.55, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4]
```

where `metrics[0]` corresponds to `documents[0]`, `metrics[1]` to `documents[1]` and so on.

Is there any good way to order the list `documents` on ascending order based on their corresponding `metrics` values?

Output should be:

```
ordered_documents = ['document1.txt', 'document3.txt', 'document5.txt', 'document2.txt', 'document4.txt']
```

or

```
ordered_documents = ['document1.txt', 'document5.txt', 'document3.txt', 'document2.txt', 'document4.txt']
```

Comment: You can use `sorted`, with a custom key they tell python how to sort: `documents = sorted(documents, key=lambda x:metrics[documents.index(x)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could zip the two lists and sort, then retain just the name in a list comprehension:

```
[v for k, v in sorted(zip(metrics, documents))]

# out:
['document1.txt',
 'document3.txt',
 'document5.txt',
 'document2.txt',
 'document4.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

documents = ['document1.txt', 'document2.txt', 'document3.txt', 'document4.txt', 'document5.txt']
metrics = [0.2, 0.55, 0.4, 0.8, 0.4]

df = pd.DataFrame({'metrics':metrics, 'documents':documents}).sort_values(by='metrics', ascending=True)
```

And then take the column you want.

```
new_metrics = df['metrics']
new_documents = df['documents']
```